# How to make high score based on collected coins?

Tags: 2d

I’m creating small 2d platformer on Unity. The core is that you have 30 sec to spend on a level + plus an enemy chasing you. You have to act fast and aggressive to get those coins. So, actually how to make the score go up after I touch a coin? And how to make it disappear after that? I thought I could make a trigger, but I want the coin to be driven by physics, because it looks cool when it falls from midair on the ground.

Answer (score 1):

insert this sample on your coins and add Coillder + trigger it

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
     if(other.gameObject.tag == "yourplayertag"){
           PlayerPrefs.SetInt("yourCoin", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("yourCoin") + 1); // if your coins stored in playerprefs

           Destroy(gameObject);
     }
}
```

and advice, you need to learn more about unity and this is not here on Stack, your question is very basic, do some research first and try many times, tutorials and unity manual will help